# Xcode Project Icon files and Organiser Archives artwork

Tags: xcode, itunes

I have all my icon files set up in my project and they are found alongside the .xcodeproj file on my Mac, and I have added them to the plist file as per the screenshot, when I build there are no warnings, but when I Archive, I get 4 warnings which I don't understand.

I found no documentation about the new "Icon file (iOS 5)" and if I should be mirroring the "Icon files" property, I tried with and without it and I still have these warnings. It's worrying because the warning explanation says it's unable to validate my application. I'm worrying about Apple submission.

If I remove this files from the plist then there is no warning, and testing on iPad and iPhone devices, the icons for settings and spotlight still work fine it seems, so these files are being used.

However the Apple docs do tell you to add references to these files in your plist.

Does the location of these files have any impact on if they're being used or not ? I would like to remove them from the root directory and into an "Artwork" directory but I can see that this now removes the preview from the Target summary.

Also in the Archive section of the Organiser I used to get the iTunesArtwork to appear - now my Icon.png is blown up and consequently very ugly. I wonder if this suggests I am doing something wrong ?

There is no clear guide to how I should treat these icons...

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

It seems like for these warnings to be avoided, you must have a folder named "Resources" in the root of your project. And import that folder into the Xcode, you still must declare in the plist, two times these icon files. 
I still don't know how to get my iTunesArtwork to be used in the Organizer's Archive view.

Comment: "I still don't know how to get my iTunesArtwork to be used in the Organizer's Archive view." I'm not sure there is currently any way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just able to figure out how to get both of these working correctly (icons without warnings and iTunesArtwork in the organizer window).

For all the icons, Xcode seems to prefer them at the root directory of the project. Then I add the icon files (iOS 5) entry:

[image: icon Files iOS5]

Then I add the icon files entry with just the iTunesArtwork files (also located in the root of the project, no extension on these)

[image: icon Files]

I don't think this part matters, but I did move them to the 'Supporting Files' group in Xcode:

[image: Supporting Files]

Comment: I guess the simple version is, use icon files (iOS5) for all your icons and launch screens, and use icon files (not the iOS5 version) for just your iTunes Artwork. I'm sure this is a bug, but this gets it working correctly. All graphics at the root of your file structure, and optionally added to the supporting files group.

Comment: At the root OR in a folder called Resources found at the root, I'm sure the Resources folder is mentioned by Apple. Thanks for the info, it's working more or less how I want now !

Comment: An update on this. So while this works great while developing, submitting an app with the double icon files entries causes an invalid binary. :(  Had to remove the non-iOS5 one to submit.

Comment: That's very interesting, I am starting to wonder if it originally isn't just a bug with Organizer...