# icon error while updating app to appStore iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icons, app-store

i am trying to update my application using application loader. when i submit the archive file, i got this error

```
    "icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper.icon57.png"!
```

[image]

i have deleted the icons from my project and tried again, but the error exist. is their any way to remove this error?

my info.plist displays these icons [image]

Comment: i got this errors while build for testing process, 
warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon@2x.png: icon dimensions (114 x 114) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could help you, i think your filenames are wrong:

[image]

I usually put this image in my dashboard so you can fast access to the filenames.

Comment: but i chooses the right dimensions for those images, can i delete the icon files from info.plist and reset it again by adding from the resources?

Comment: It's not enough the dimension, you've to set the file names as my screenshot. And yes, you can delete the wrong items in the plist and reset them with the right icons present in your main bundle.

Comment: yes i renamed the icon files and made changes in info.plist also, Then I add the icon files (iOS 5) entry and removed from icon files. now it works, thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Mat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617137/662605), also please check out this thread that you may need, I had these errors even with the correct name, so this could be interesting:

[Xcode Project Icon files and Organiser Archives artwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769782/xcode-project-icon-files-and-organiser-archives-artwork)

Comment: thank you,your link helped me to overcome those errors,  I add the icon files (iOS 5) entry and removed from icon files. now it works, thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

Your app icon must be named as Icon.png which is of size 57*57.You have to rename the image and change that name in the info plist.App icon for retina display should be of size 114*114.And it should be named as Icon@2x.png.Rename ur this image and correct it in the info plist too.And ur splash screen should be named as Default.png

Comment: i changed the name and the image size is same as recommented by apple, 55x57 and 114x114.but the problem remains.

Comment: warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon@2x.png: icon dimensions (114 x 114) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

Comment: Try to remove the icon images and add again.And make sure the images are of correct size.

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes due to the compression that apple does during compiling. You should make sure the file type is correctly set to "Icon". Click on the icon in the project navigator and under "Identity and Type" you can set the File Type to "Icon"

Comment: thankyou for your feedback, i made changes as you said. this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I ended up with some empty keys in my plist file. I deleted all Icon plist entries, saved the plist, and then added the icons a second time through the Target Summary page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the steps detailed here, many of which have solved this problem previously.

The only way I could get this to work recently was to open the archive file (right click in the Organizer->Archives) and open the actual bundle that's going to be uploaded (show package contents for the archive and then the .app file inside the archive) and copy the icon files directly into there. Resubmitted the previously failed archive then solves the issue.