# Xcode 5 Missing Code Signing Entitlements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, loader, signing

I'm using xcode 5 and trying to upload my app to itunes connect through application loader.

Okay so for the last 5 days I've tried to resolve this issue. I've looked through forums and written to apple, but I've yet to find a solution.

What I've done so far:

- renewed all provisioning profiles and refreshed them in xcode
- the bundle ID is correct field out
- checked apple's documentation
- under  capabilities the only things that are enabled are gamecenter and IAP, so there's no missing keys

And here is the problem:

```
1. Apple's web service operation was not succesful

2. Unable to authenticate the package: 717608008.itmsp

3. ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx' for executable 'Payload/xxxxxxx.app/file name'."" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

Comment: Still need help with this?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, at a total loss for what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I encountered few days ago. Check that your project [include all required icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493430/602257) with the correct names (in the resources folder and the plist file).